# aws sync doesn't download the file and instead create an empty directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The file I'm trying to download is:

```
s3://ont-open-data/gm24385_q20_2021.10/analysis/20210805_1713_5C_PAH79257_0e41e938/guppy_5.0.15_sup/align_unfiltered/chr19/calls2ref.bam
```

This is an open dataset. I followed the tutorial here: https://labs.epi2me.io/tutorials/.
The command I used was:

```
aws s3 sync --no-sign-request s3://ont-open-data/gm24385_q20_2021.10/analysis/20210805_1713_5C_PAH79257_0e41e938/guppy_5.0.15_sup/align_unfiltered/chr19/calls2ref.bam destination.bam
```

However, instead of downloading the file, aws simply created an empty directory named `destination.bam`, which makes no sense...

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.15.15 Python/3.6.10 Linux/4.4.0-210-generic botocore/1.10.15
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't solve the problem with `sync`, but I realized that `cp` works! The following command downloaded the file:

```
aws s3 cp --no-sign-request s3://ont-open-data/gm24385_q20_2021.10/analysis/20210805_1713_5C_PAH79257_0e41e938/guppy_5.0.15_sup/align_unfiltered/chr19/calls2ref.bam destination.bam
```